# Bootstrap NavBar, anyone have any idea how to change the behavior of the mobile navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, navbar

Anyone know how to force the Bootstrap mobile menu 3 stripes to be a little on the left and then put a little image on the most right (the place where the mobile menu 3 stripes originally was)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a:

```
<div class="pull-right navbar-toggle">
    <img .../>
</div>
```

right after the navbar header element

http://jsfiddle.net/rhxaz5yL/